# Recalculate bone roll without ruining the animation

Tags: animation, bones

I have (what I hope) is a simple question. A while ago I rigged a character up with an armature, and since then I've made quite a few animations for it. Since beginning my project, I learned about bone rolls, and found out that the ones I had been using weren't properly set, since I couldn't properly mirror poses along the X-axis:

[image]

I looked into it, and to fix it I need to Recalculate Rolls for bones. However, when I do so (recalculating with the **Local +X Tangent**), all of the animations I have made so far become distorted:

[image]

Now, I understand why this happens, but I don't know how to automatically recalculate my animations to adjust for this change. There really are too many animations for it to be viable to remake them, so is there anything that can be done?